# @property setter for BOOL

Tags: objective-c, properties, boolean

I'm having problems setting a BOOL using `@property` and `@synthesize`.
I'm using `@property BOOL isPaused;` And I can get it by using `[myObject isPaused];` but I cannot manage to set it. I'd like to use `[myObject setPaused: NO];`. I also tried `@property (setter=setPaused) BOOL isPaused;` but if I'm not mistaking, then I need to write that setter myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the dot notation?

```
myObject.isPaused = YES;
return myObject.isPaused;
```

---

If your property is declared as `@property BOOL isPaused`, then the setter is always called as

```
[myObject setIsPaused:YES];
```

To rename the setter you must provide the full signature *including the colons*:

```
@property(setter=setPaused:) BOOL isPaused;
...
[myObject setPaused:YES];
```

---

BTW, the naming convention is not to include verbs in a property.

```
@property(getter=isPaused) BOOL paused;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the dot notation before but I'm not a big fan of it. I also couldn't get it to work somehow? Anyway, I forgot the capital 'I' in setIsPaused... And I didn't know you needed the colon in the setter= attribute.

Comment: Actually, "isPaused" is the correct naming convention in this case.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202-BCIGGFCC

Comment: @Jeremy: `-isPaused` as a getter is fine, but I'm talking about the property name, like [`.playing` (`-isPlaying`, `-setPlaying:`)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW1).

Comment: I'd say that naming convention applies to properties too because properties are really just accessors.  The same considerations should apply.

Comment: +1 for Jeremy for sharing the official documentation link about naming conventions.

Comment: For adjectives, you leave off the "is" from the property name: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE