# Naming convention for local BOOL variables in Objective-C and Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'd like to ask about naming convention for **local** `BOOL` variables in Cocoa projects. Which of the following is preferred?

```
// Style #1
BOOL isNightModeEnabled = NO;

// Style #2
BOOL nightModeEnabled = NO;
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938345/does-xcode-4-5-2-automatically-prefix-synthesized-bool-getters-with-is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891122/property-setter-for-bool

Comment: http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/05/objective-c-tuesdays-changing-default.html

Comment: +1 I liked this question, and did half an hour search and reading, apple documentation, blog, SO etc

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Just FYI, this question is about local variables, not setters/getters.

Comment: Yes, And +1 was only for this, this is the only question for variables, not for properties and methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought about it a bit more.

Apple's own Cocoa methods don't prefix `BOOL` variables that are used as arguments:

```
... whenHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
... animated:(BOOL)animated
```

The same applies for Xcode's autocompletion for setters. So, it seems that prefixing local variables with `is` is **not a good idea** because one would end up with some variables prefixed with `is` and others not. Therefore using `is` is a good naming convention **for getters**, not local variables.

Comment: I always used `self.isRead=NO;` and never used `setIsRed:NO`... So Even I am waiting for response from some big bosses to comment :)

Comment: @JeremyP From Coding Guidelines for Cocoa (section Accessor Methods): If the property is expressed as an adjective, the format is `(BOOL)isAdjective` and `(void)setAdjective:(BOOL)flag`.

Answer (score 1):

Style 2 is good. It makes properties and KVO-style names read better:

```
-(void)setNightModeEnabled;
-(BOOL)nightModeEnabled;
```

or

```
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter=isNightModeEnabled) BOOL nightModeEnabled;
```

Check the docs: [Guidelines for Cocoa Naming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html).

Comment: The question is about local variables, not instance variables.

Comment: Oh now I see the bold LOCAL adjective. I usually just go with whatever reads best. 'is' in front does look good in an if statement.

Comment: But you got me thinking! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is for:

```
bool isNightModeEnabled = false;
```

It reads more like English to put the 'is' in.

I always use the C99 boolean type in preference to Apple's `BOOL` except where required to do so by the Cocoa API.  This is because `BOOL` is just a typedef to a char which can be problematic for booleans.  For instance, the following unit test fails, even though it's not what you might expect from C

```
-(void) testBool
{
    int a = 513;
    int b = 257;
    STAssertTrue(a - b, @"Should be true");
}
```

The reason is that a - b is 256 and when cast down to the `BOOL` parameter type all the non zero bits are lost.  If the first parameter of `STAssertTrue()` was `bool` instead, the cast would work as expected.

Comment: Thank god, anyone is here who uses `isXXXX` just like me :)

Comment: Yeah, but isn't it inconsistent if Apple's method arguments don't use `is`? Like, for example, an argument `animated` is always defined as `(BOOL)animated`. Then, in method body, you would end up with a mix like `if (animated && isNightEnabled)`, no?

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic I don't work for Apple.  I don't *have* to use their naming conventions and I don't religiously put 'is' in front of all my booleans. I try to use the variable name that tells me most about what it is for and often that means put 'is' on booleans.

Comment: @JeremyP Thank you for your answer! I see your point and was just curious whether you mix it if there's, say, `animated` and then your own `bool` variable.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic if you think about it, I don't often have to.  As `animated` is an argument to a method defined by Apple, only they will be putting it in if statements.  If I override the method, I'll make a call based on circumstances.